# Coordinating highlighting between two tables

Tags: d3.js

The challenge is this: 2 coordinated tables, 1 with an overview that is laid out on a grid, the other contains detailed information about the cells in the first table. (This overview is used for other information as well, which has been removed from the minimal example below.) Mousing over either one will highlight both. Clicking on the overview table will hide or show the rows of the data view.

The problem is that the data is being defined by a JSON data object and the order of that object is very important. It's important that the data is mapped to the overview without reordering either. There may be cells not represented in the data view that are in the overview and nothing bad should happen.

http://fiddle.jshell.net/g8z5h/14/

The problem is using select all lets d3 define the order things will be taken. I need to coordinate the mapping myself. I'm hoping there's an elegant solution to this that doesn't involve writing separate mouseover and mouse click functions.

Comment: To clarify:  The order they are displaying in the table is the order you want, you just want the highlighting to match based on the data, not based on the order?  You'll have to give them classes based on the data in that case, and select based on that class, instead of selecting with `nth-of-type`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a key function to tie the selection to your data:

- http://bost.ocks.org/mike/selection/#key
- http://bost.ocks.org/mike/constancy/#key-functions

Comment: @Cymon, did this answer your question. If it did, please accept it :)